# Document a function in a different namespace

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a function that is implemented and documented in a namespace called `implementation`. I have another namespace `useful` where I use `using` to expose that function. I do not want to document the `implementation` namespace. I instead want to have the function documented under the `useful` namespace. I am looking for a simple way to do this in doxygen.

Below is a simple example I want `useful_function` documentation to be under `namespace useful`. Right now, it is under `namespace implementation`.

```
/// \file test.cpp
/// \brief This is a brief description.
///
///
/// This is a longer description

namespace implementation{

    /// This is a useful function
    void useful_function(){}
}

namespace useful{

    using implementation::useful_function;
}

/// \namespace useful
/// This is a namespace that has useful functions


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    useful::useful_function();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useful_function` is in namespace `implementation`, so that's where it shall be documented.

The `using` statement doesn't change this fundamental fact.